# 15 second delay before first call to database in EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

After having the C# ASP.NET MVC with EF 6 application in production for about 3 months, we are noticing one call to the database taking considerably longer than it used to.  It started out taking less than one second for the operation.  With no gradual increase, it jumped to 15 seconds.

I have enabled logging on the EF context.  Here is the code.

```
public async Task<int> SetToProcessing(string[] documentIds, string userName)
{
    if (documentIds.Count() == 0)
        return 0;

    var assigned = 0;
    using (var db = new InvoiceDeliveryContext())
    {
        db.Database.Log = message => logger.Debug("EF6-" + message);
        foreach (var id in ConvertToLong(documentIds))
        {
            if (id == 0)
                continue;
            var doc = db.Documents.Find(id);
            if (doc.Status == DocumentStates.Processing)
            {
                logger.Debug($"Document Id {id} not being set to processed.  Already set to Processing.");
                continue;
            }
            assigned++;
            doc.AssignedTo = userName;
            doc.Status = DocumentStates.Processing;
            doc.History.Add(new History
            {
                Audit = "Set back to Processing.",
                CreatedBy = userName,
                Document = doc,
            });

            logger.Debug($"Assigned Document with ID={id} for Processing to {userName}.");
        }
        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e, "An exception occurred trying to set documents to processing.");
        }
    }
    return assigned;
}
```

Here is the resulting log.  Notice after the connection is opened, a ~15 second delay occurs.

```
[5] 2017-07-27 06:47:32.4742 EF6-Opened connection at 7/27/2017 6:47:32 AM -05:00  
[5] 2017-07-27 06:47:47.0677 EF6-SELECT TOP (2)   
    [Extent1].[DocumentId] AS [DocumentId],   
    [Extent1].[AssignedTo] AS [AssignedTo],   
    [Extent1].[ApprovedBy] AS [ApprovedBy],   
    [Extent1].[AttachmentId] AS [AttachmentId],   
    [Extent1].[FileLocation] AS [FileLocation],   
    [Extent1].[FileSize] AS [FileSize],   
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],   
    [Extent1].[Pages] AS [Pages],   
    [Extent1].[Part] AS [Part],   
    [Extent1].[Parts] AS [Parts],   
    [Extent1].[IsMerged] AS [IsMerged],   
    [Extent1].[ReceivedOn] AS [ReceivedOn],   
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status],   
    FROM [InvoiceDelivery].[Documents] AS [Extent1]  
    WHERE [Extent1].[DocumentId] = @p0   
[5] 2017-07-27 06:47:47.0980 EF6--- p0: '7149' (Type = Int64)  
[5] 2017-07-27 06:47:47.0980 EF6--- Executing at 7/27/2017 6:47:47 AM -05:00  
[5] 2017-07-27 06:47:47.1401 EF6--- Completed in 28 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

I have captured the logs of the above process multiple times and they all show around 15 seconds of delay.  Other queries do not experience this issue.  Any idea why I would see this delay?

### EDIT

I am unable to reproduce the delay using a new console app.
    `private static async Task GoAsync()
     {
         var repo = new InvoiceRepository();
         await repo.SetToProcessing(new[] { "7149" }, "JD Montgomery");
     }`

Comment: This looks like a straightforward query. Is there any part of your process that is holding a write lock to that table? Perhaps, something that you may be running on a 15-second interval?

Comment: Does this happen only on the production machine? Or also on your local machine?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight There is a Windows Service that is pretty active during the day.  It polls the database every 20 seconds looking for work.  However, with me being unable to reproduce outside of the MVC app, the Windows Service doesn't seem to be the issue.  I will continue to investigate a write lock.

Comment: Looks peculiar indeed. At first I thought it'd be something like a missing index, or a parameter/index type mismatch (since I saw your `@p0` is `Int64`), but a 15 second delay *before* the query is executed... You need to have a look at your SQL Server. See how things behave in SQL Server Management Studio. See if the "Auto Close" option is ON on the database.

Comment: @s.m.  production code and database, it occurs on my machine as well as production.

Comment: Re trying the query in SQL Server Management Studio, note the following difference in behaviour between ADO.NET and SSMS (`ARITHABORT`). When testing in SSMS, make sure you try both `ARITHABORT ON` and `ARITHABORT OFF`): http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html (search for ARITHABORT in the article)

Comment: I'd like to clarify the title:  is the proc taking 15 seconds before it starts to run, then it runs quickly, or is it now taking 15 seconds to run?  The title makes it sound like the former, but the question reads like the latter.

Comment: @Amy EF opens the connection, waits ~15 seconds, then executes the command in 28ms.  I'm not sure how to clarify the question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I resolved it.  If you will add your comment as an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: @Monty0018 I'm glad that you were able to resolve the problem! My comment was more of a question than an answer, that's why I didn't post an answer. Your own answer explains what was going on, so you should mark it as a solution when the system lets you do that (I think it requires a two-day delay, but I may be wrong on that). Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging.  I don't log everything but several services including the UI layer log to the same database table.  With DEBUG level, this issue is occurring.  Once I drop my level down or stop logging to the database, the issue disappears.

I'm guessing that there was a lock on the Log table.